# Connecting to multiple servers through PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to make a script, or just find a way, to use a .txt file that has a list of servers, and go through the list connected to each, or try to connect to each to see which servers belong to me. If I can connect, they're mine, if not then I need to send that server name to a file. There are 600+ servers so I can't enter credentials and have been trying to find a way using New-SSHSession that doesn't ask for -Username or -Password. What I have so far is below, I've just started PowerShell so my knowledge is limited, what you see is what I've been trying to get working before finally coming here.

```
#$pass = Get-Content C:\securestring.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString
 $pass = Read-Host -AsSecureString "Enter Password"
 $pass2 = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto(
 [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pass))


 ForEach ($cname in Get-Content "C:\testingconnections\testconnect.txt")
            {         
            New-SshSession -ComputerName $cname -Username $env:USERNAME -Password $pass2 *>> 'C:\testingconnections\error.txt' 
            Remove-SshSession $cname
            }
```

Comment: Perhaps you'd better use a `New-PSSession` instead of going with SSH, if those servers are running Windows. Check `get-help about_remote` for details on what to do to allow Powershell to connect. And if you are using `New-SSHSession` check the module manuals to find out what does this return if the SSH session was established successfully. Also with SSH you don't need to run conversion to/from `SecureString`, just use plain text, or if you're trying to hide the input, use `ConvertFrom-SecureString` instead of this marshal call set. (It's less prone to errors)